Galerkin Method - Why does integration-by-parts eliminate need to enforce Neumann boundaries?
I've posted this to MathStackexchange but I figured I'd also post here as well as I have yet to receive an answer on my original post, and that I would be more likely to encounter users of the Galerkin method here than on MathStackexchange.
Disclaimer: I have not taken any class in functional analysis and the only class I have ever taken in differential equations is at the barest-bones introductory level.
From what I know of the Galerkin method, it is about approximating $u$, to a invertible linear system $Au=f$, as a vector in some subspace of the original square-integrable function space that $u$ resides in; aka, find the vector $\hat{u}$ in some subspace $X$ such that $(f-A\hat{u}) \perp X$.
Obviously, if I want to approximate $u$ as the linear combination of some set of functions $\psi_n$, I need to make sure that those functions satisfy the vector space axioms (because otherwise the functions would not span a vector space). This makes dealing with boundary conditions difficult, because nonhomogeneous boundary conditions are not preserved under arbitrary linear combinations (and subsequently there cannot exist a vector space of functions whose boundary conditions are nonhomogeneous).
However, this can be ameliorated by approximating $u$ as the sum of a a vector in a trial space that satisfies the homogeneous version of the boundary conditions plus some function that satisfies the nonhomogeneous boundary conditions. Of course, if both nonhomogeneous Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions are present, this becomes complicated to implement.
For differential equations, it appears that using integration-by-parts allows us to neglect enforcing Neumann boundary conditions on our trial space, as claimed in places like page 10 of
Zahr's lecture notes on weighted residual methods: https://mjzahr.github.io/content/ame40541/spr20/ch03-wres-solo.pdf
Zahr makes the claim:

"Since the [weak formulation] incorporates the natural BCs, the trial space does not have to be restricted to functions that satisfy the natural BCs (only essential BCs)"

Why is this the case? If we have a basis $\{\psi_n\}$ for our trial space, why is it that integration-by-parts ensures that the coefficients for each basis will still result in the linear combination respecting Neumann boundary conditions even if we don't enforce such a requirement on the trial space?
Meanwhile, the answerer of this related StackExchange question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4861034/how-to-solve-a-boundary-value-problem-with-neumann-boundary-conditions-using-the
...claims the following:

The weird trick with Neumann boundary conditions is to simply replace $u′(1)$ in the equation with what the BVP wants it to be (so $0$ in your case), rather than forcing $u′(1)$ to actually be $0$. There are a bunch of ways to support why this is the right way to do things, but as a newcomer it is easier to just think of it as a weird trick.

What exactly are those "bunch of ways to support why this is the right way to do things"??? And on a related note, is there a way to generalize this beyond (a sum of) differential operators, or is this trick exclusive to differential equations?

Example: $$\int_{\Omega}v f = \int_{\Omega}v(-\Delta)u = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + \int_{\partial\Omega}v \partial_n u.$$ If $\partial_n u = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$ then the boundary term becomes zero. If $\partial_n u = g$ on $\partial\Omega$ then you would have $\int_{\partial\Omega} v g$ to account for those, so they do not magically disappear.

It isn't magic, but it is a nice coincidence that if you forget the boundary terms it corresponds to something nice

@lightxbulb The integration-by-parts manipulations is something I understand, but what I don't understand is why such manipulations alleviate the need to force the trial space to conform to Neumann boundary conditions.
To put it another way: if I don't force the trial space to conform to Neumann BCs, why would integration-by-parts be able to guarantee that my trial function would still be able to satisfy such BCs?

Because you put in the condition in the equation explcitly, so they are naturally satisfied, pun intended. If you consider higher Laplacian powers then you would get a lot more conditions that are natural and essential.

@whpowell96 "if you forget the boundary terms" - the physicist's approach.

You could also frame it like this: Iff $\partial_n u = \partial_n u_\text{BC}$ then the boundary term becomes zero, because ...
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Form I}:& \quad \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v - \int_{\partial \Omega} v \partial_n u &= -\int_{\Omega} vf &\quad \big | \quad\text{apply BC + perform ibp again}\
\text{Form II}:& \quad \int_{\Omega} v\Delta u \hspace{0.7cm} +  \int_{\partial \Omega} v \left(\partial_n u - \partial_n u_{\text{BC}}\right) &= -\int_{\Omega} vf
\end{align}
$$
